# Overwriting the middle of a file from a block device *without* truncating file?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, file-management

I have a Linux (Kubuntu) system with a large (~20Gb) file which I would like to mess with. Specifically, I want to copy the entire contents of another large file (~12Gb) to the middle of this file, and keep the bits of the file which are not overwritten.

This is what I want to happen, with the text between the pipes representing file contents:

Before:

```
outfile: |abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz|
infile:  |123456789|
```

After:

```
outfile: |abcdef123456789pqrstuvwxyz|
(infile is here ^^^^^^^^^)
```

I tried this:

```
dd if=infile of=outfile seek=162
```

(162 is the number of sectors I want to offset by in outfile)

But this is what happened:

```
outfile: |abcdef123456789|
(missing part of outfile ^)
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify conv=notrunc to dd.  From the manpage

> Any regular output file is truncated unless the notrunc conversion value
>                 is specified.  If an initial portion of the output file is
>                 seeked past (see the oseek operand), the output file is trun-
>                 cated at that point.

Comment: Works great, thank you so much! I read dd --help but didn't try the man page. Stupid me...